# Checking through an Object and returning if the element is found

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am trying to return true for items found within an Object although some arrays within the object have more than one element within it. For example selectedEventTypes[9] has an array of [cancelled,cancelled2,cancelled3], although whenever the item.eventType is cancelled2 it will never realise that it is within the Object and always return false for this.

```
private function eventFilterFucntion(item:Object):Boolean
{   
    if(selectedEventTypes.indexOf(item.eventType)>-1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you show how did you created the `selectedEventTypes` array and the `item` object ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have defined **selectedEventTypes** as an **Array** of an **Array** like:

```
private var selectedEventTypes:Array = [["A1", "A2"],
        ["B1","B2"],
        ["C1","C2"],
        ["D1","D2"],
        ["E1","E2"],
        ["F1","F2"],
        ["G1","G2"],
        ["H1","H2"],
        ["I1","I2"],
        ["Cancelled", "Cancelled2", "Cancelled3"],
        ["Received","Last"]];
```

where

```
selectedEventTypes[9] = ["Cancelled", "Cancelled2", "Cancelled3"]
```

In this case you can change your **eventFilterFunction** as below:

```
private function eventFilterFucntion(item:Object):Boolean
    {
        for each(var eachArray:Array in selectedEventTypes)
        {
            if(eachArray.indexOf(item.eventType) > -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Try this sample application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    private var selectedEventTypes:Array = [["A1", "A2"],
        ["B1","B2"],
        ["C1","C2"],
        ["D1","D2"],
        ["E1","E2"],
        ["F1","F2"],
        ["G1","G2"],
        ["H1","H2"],
        ["I1","I2"],
        ["Cancelled", "Cancelled2", "Cancelled3"],
        ["Received","Last"]];
    [Bindable]
    private var myArrayCollectionOriginal:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {name:"State 1",eventType:"Submitted"},
        {name:"State 2",eventType:"Cancelled2"},
        {name:"State 3",eventType:"Pending"},
        {name:"State 4",eventType:"Cancelled3"},
        {name:"State 5",eventType:"Failed"},
        {name:"State 6",eventType:"Received"}
        ]);
    [Bindable]
    private var otherArrayCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
    private function applyFilterButtonClicked():void
    {
        otherArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(myArrayCollectionOriginal.source)
        otherArrayCollection.filterFunction = eventFilterFucntion;
        otherArrayCollection.refresh();
    }

    private function eventFilterFucntion(item:Object):Boolean
    {
        for each(var eachArray:Array in selectedEventTypes)
        {
            if(eachArray.indexOf(item.eventType) > -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    ]]></fx:Script>
<s:HGroup verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
    <s:Panel title="Original collection">
        <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{myArrayCollectionOriginal}"/>
    </s:Panel>
    <s:Button click="{applyFilterButtonClicked()}" label="Apply Filter" />
    <s:Panel title="Filtered Output">
        <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{otherArrayCollection}"/>
    </s:Panel>
</s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```